# Pkg-config file is on the pkg-config path but can not be found by configure script

Tags: c, dynamic-linking, pkg-config, libssh2, libvirt

I am trying to install libvirt from source. The version I am trying to install is 1.2.7. I want libssh2 enabled. Here is how I call the configure script:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/administrator/dev/workspaces/libvirt/built/libvirt-1.2.7/  --with-sasl --with-qemu --with-lxc --with-gnutls --with-remote --with-ssh2 --with-polkit
```

I got the following error:

> configure: error: You must install the libssh2 >= 1.3 pkg-config module to compile libvirt

I downloaded the libssh2 lib version 1.4.3 and installed it using the default options:

```
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Here is some useful info:

```
$ sudo ldconfig
$ sudo updatedb
$ locate libssh2.so
/usr/local/lib/libssh2.so
/usr/local/lib/libssh2.so.1
/usr/local/lib/libssh2.so.1.0.1
$ locate libssh2.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libssh2.pc
$ pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig
```

Obviously the libssh2.pc file is on the pkg-config path. However, when I tried executing the configure script for libvirt, the same error occurred. Any ideas what I am doing wrong ? Thank you.

EDIT: Fragment of the config.log file:

```
 34475 configure:59141: checking for SSH2
 34476 configure:59148: $PKG_CONFIG --exists --print-errors "libssh2 >= 1.3"
 34477 configure:59151: $? = 0
 34478 configure:59165: $PKG_CONFIG --exists --print-errors "libssh2 >= 1.3"
 34479 configure:59168: $? = 0
 34480 configure:59182: result: no
 34481 Package libssl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
 34482 Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libssl.pc'
 34483 to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
 34484 Package 'libssl', required by 'libssh2', not found
 34485 configure:59225: error: You must install the libssh2 >= 1.3 pkg-config module to compile libvirt
...
34576 ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_set=
34577 ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_value=
34578 ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_PATH_set=
34579 ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_PATH_value=
34580 ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_set=
34581 ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_value=
...
34874 ac_cv_path_ac_pt_PKG_CONFIG=/usr/bin/pkg-config
36432 PKG_CONFIG='/usr/bin/pkg-config'
36433 PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=''
36434 PKG_CONFIG_PATH=''
```

Comment: Try figuring out what it bails out on in the config.log file

Comment: Just added fragments from the log file which looks related to the problem

Comment: Yes, it's complaining about a dependent of libssh2, it can't find libssl